# Sklearn TruncatedSVD() ValueError: n_components must be < n_features

Tags: scikit-learn, kaggle

Hi I'am trying to run script for a Kaggle competition.

you can see the whole script [here](https://www.kaggle.com/vabatista/home-depot-product-search-relevance/test-script-1)

But when I run this script i get an ValueError

```
ValueError: n_components must be < n_features; got 1 >= 1
```

Can somebody tell me please how to find out how many features there are at this point.
I don't think it will be usefull when I set n_components to 0.
I also read the documentation but I can't solve that issue.
Greetz
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly likely that the shape of your data matrix is wrong: It seems to have only one column. That needs to be fixed. Use a debugger to figure out what goes into the `fit` method of the `TruncatedSVD`, or unravel the pipeline and do the steps by hand.

As for the error message, if it is due to a matrix with one column, this makes sense: You can only have maximally as many components as features. Since you are using `TruncatedSVD` it additionally assumes that you don't want the full feature space, hence the strict inequality.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I'll change the model.